Extracting email address from the sign in page in Azure AD B2C for third party provider
I want to create a UX where the user can enter their email + password and select "Sign in" to login with password - OR to enter their email address and select "Login with custom provider" which delegates the auth to this provider. This question is regarding the latter.
I have added a custom provider through a ClaimsProviderSelection in my CombinedSignInAndSignUp orchestration step.
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="CustomProvider" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

I want to extract the email address from the api.signuporsignin page to send to this provider - how can I achieve this?
Through my app insights logs, it appears that there are no claims capture from the input if I select the "Login with custom provider button".


B2C can only act on the login once a button is pressed.
Typing something into a text field does nothing.
If you had a second B2C page following this, for example, you could make the login an input claim, and it would pre-populate.
However, when you click a button for an external IDP, B2C just passes control. It doesn't pass any info.
"login_hint" is sometimes used to achieve this across B2C tenants if you use OIDC.
.

If you could build an webpage that is assigned as contentdefinition to this policy, you could do something.
Create an HTML page with all fields such as email, password, signin and 'login with custom provider'.
You could hide everything within the 'API' div so that none of the ADB2C injected elements is displayed.
You could then write javascript code in such a way that the email address you type into your HTML input field is copied to ADB2C injected input field. Similarly, your javascript can read the id of ADB2C injected element: 'login with custom provider' and point the same to the HTML element: 'login with custom provider'.
This way, when the HTML element 'login with custom provider' is clicked, you already have the email address in the HTML input field. You could collect the email address through Javascript and send it to the other provider.
